# Why is the state of the hook changing even when I use the preventdefault() function in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

recently I started learning React and I cannot understand why onSubmit the e.preventDefault() function is simply not working as it is supposed to... Instead of waiting until I click the "Deposit" or "Change" buttons for the value displayed on the React components hooks state to change, their state is changing as I type into the form.

The preventDefault() function should not let the hook state to change until I hit the button, hence the onSubmit{}. However, the state changes as soon as I type a new character.

```
function App() {
  const [depositValue, setDepositValue] = useState('');
  
  const handleDepositValue = (e) => {
    setDepositValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
          <div className="col">
          <form onSubmit={handleDepositSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="0" onChange={handleDepositValue} defaultValue={depositValue} />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Deposit</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is a JavaScript API not related to react hooks at all. Submit is a different event than click and they run intendently.

Comment: @Konrad ok I deleted the React hooks from tags. I thought they are related as Developer tools - React components display the state as 'hook'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the same mistake when I was first starting with React. `preventDefault()` is typically used to prevent a browser reload/refresh. This would never stop a state update in React. Since you are using `onChange`, your state is going to update for each keystroke in that input.  [Here is a link to an article I think would be helpful and relevant to your situation.](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-preventdefault/)

From looking at your code, I don't think that the fact that your `depositValue` state is updating on each keystroke is a problem. That is pretty typical for React forms so I wouldn't worry about it. Good luck with your studies!